# Count error converting varchar to numeric, also with an IN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need a count of many teachers teach specific course numbers, grouped by `schoolid`, and by course. I am getting the following error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1.  Error converting data type
>   varchar to numeric.

I have to join a table to ensure I can pull the `schoolid`. I am relatively new to SQL and I don't know what I'm doing incorrectly. It seems there is a fundamental piece of logic I am missing. I appreciate any help you can provide.

If you need any further information, please let me know. Thank you.

```
SELECT 
 TC.COURSE
 ,COUNT(tc.teacherUserName) AS TotalTeachers

FROM Teacherclasses AS Tc
JOIN Sites AS S ON Tc.Schoolid = S.Schoolid
WHERE Schoolyear = '2015'
AND TC.Course IN (
  17.0010000
, 23.0010000
, 27.0110000
, 36.0010000
, 41.0110000
, 45.0010000
, 23.1011070
, 27.1110070
, 23.1011080
, 27.1110080
, 23.0010010
, 27.0110010
, 41.0110010
, 45.0010010
, 55.0010050
, 23.9010000
, 27.9110000
, 41.9110000
, 45.9010000
, 23.8010000
, 27.8110000
, 41.8110000
, 45.8010000
)
GROUP BY TC.Course--, TC.SchoolID
```

Comment: Your list of IN values are numeric as posted. I suspect you have some values in there that are character based. Wrap those values in single quotes to make them string literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
SELECT 
 TC.COURSE
 ,COUNT(tc.teacherUserName) AS TotalTeachers

FROM Teacherclasses AS Tc
JOIN Sites AS S ON Tc.Schoolid = S.Schoolid
WHERE Schoolyear = '2015'
AND TC.Course IN (
  '17.0010000'
, '23.0010000'
, '27.0110000'
, '36.0010000'
, '41.0110000'
, '45.0010000'
, '23.1011070'
, '27.1110070'
, '23.1011080'
, '27.1110080'
, '23.0010010'
, '27.0110010'
, '41.0110010'
, '45.0010010'
, '55.0010050'
, '23.9010000'
, '27.9110000'
, '41.9110000'
, '45.9010000'
, '23.8010000'
, '27.8110000'
, '41.8110000'
, '45.8010000'
)
GROUP BY TC.Course--, TC.SchoolID
```

Comment: Yes, this should. Would be nice to explain to @JM1 why it's happening. See my answer.

Comment: I did that in my initial comment on the original post. :D

Comment: Glad that worked for you. Do you understand the reason why it works? That is far more important than fixing the query.

Answer (score 3):

You have some value in `Teacherclasses.Course` that cannot be converted to numeric, but it must have to be convertible as you are comparing it to numbers in your IN clause.

Either correct the value in `Teacherclasses.Course` or pass your arguments between single quotes in the IN clause.